# Download a div innerHTML containing "#" by js

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to set a button to download an SVG code inside a div, but the SVG contains hash (#) and the code cannot be downloaded after the hash with my way.

I tried to create a js function to add an  tag and then download it by onclick function.

```
function download() {
    var a = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = modedid.concat(".svg");
    a.href = "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("svgWin").innerHTML;
    a.click();
}
```

I expected to get all of my SVG  content but anything after the first hash in it won't be included on final result.

Comment: Can you provide the _html_ from what you are trying to get the _svg_?

Comment: @dreygur the main question is how to bypass that hash character on svg code. As it's obvious, the svg code is inside a div with id="svgWin"

Comment: You should supply a sample of the related HTML. Have you tried *encodeURIComponent*?

Comment: @RobG That's it. Thanks I got my answer. %23 instead of #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been exporting my svgs as svg files like this for weeks and it works wonderfully for me. Save the svg html as a svg file using blob and ObjectURLs

```js
// html svg element
var svg = document.getElementById("svg"),
    // get the window URL element on any browser
    DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

// encode the svg to a string
var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);

// convert serialized data to blob of type svg+xml
var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});

// get object url for the data blob
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

/* download the data as a file */
// create a click event
var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: false,
    cancelable: true
});
// create an anchor for the download and the file using the image URI data
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('download', 'outputVectorGraphic.svg');
a.setAttribute('href', url);
a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

// activate the event
a.dispatchEvent(event);

// revoke the url
DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

```html
<div id="svgWrapper">
  <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width='50px' height='50px'>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="blue"/>
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r=5px fill="red" />
  </svg>
</div>
```